# Alignment of Chapter Numbers in Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, alignment, octavo

I have created a table of contents that looks like the following:

[image: My TOC]

But I would like the chapter numbers (in Roman) and the chapter titles to be aligned as in the following:

[image: Desired TOC]

I am doing something along the following lines:

```
\documentclass[10pt,largepost]{octavo}%

\usepackage{titlesec, tocloft}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\centering\normalfont\large\scshape}{}{18pt}{\large}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{40pt}

\titleformat{\part}[display]
  {\normalfont\Large\filcenter\scshape\bfseries}
  {\thepart}{18pt}{\large}
\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Book One}

\chapter[I \emph{Maecenas atavis}]{\textsc{i}\\maecenas atavis}

\chapter[II \emph{Jam satis}]{\textsc{ii}\\jam satis}

\chapter[III \emph{Sic te diva}]{\textsc{iii}\\sic te diva}

\chapter[IV \emph{Solvitur acris hiems}]{\textsc{iv}\\solvitur acris hiems}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[10pt,largepost]{octavo}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec,tocloft}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\centering\normalfont\large\scshape}{\thechapter}{18pt}{\large}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{40pt}

\titleformat{\part}[display]
  {\normalfont\Large\filcenter\scshape\bfseries}
  {\thepart}{18pt}{\large}
\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\def\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{1cm}
\def\cftchappresnum{\normalfont\hfill}
\def\cftchapaftersnum{.\space}
\def\cftchapdotsep{\cftdotsep}
\def\cftchapfont{\normalfont\itshape}
\def\cftchappagefont{\normalfont}
\def\cftdot{{\normalfont.}}
\cftpagenumbersoff{part}
\def\cftpartfont{\large\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part*{Book One}

\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{10pt}{\small ODE}\par}

\chapter{Maecenas atavis}

\chapter{Jam satis}

\chapter{Sic te diva}

\chapter{Solvitur acris hiems}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Many thanks, hair-splitter!

Comment: One more question... Please forgive me if not according to the proper etiquette. I would like the chapter numbers to restart within each part. Is there a simple way to do so?

Comment: Try this: `\part*{Book Two}\setcounter{chapter}{0}`

Comment: Works! Thank you, again!